# Navigation bar height decreased when push ios13

Tags: uinavigationbar, height, navbar, navigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

When i move to view controller after making navigationbar.ishidden = false the navbar height decreases and there is a black space between navbar and uiview
And when i move down the notification screen navbar height increase

### Code

```swift
viewController = PlaceOrderViewController(nibName: "PlaceOrderViewController", bundle: nil) 
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true 
viewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false 
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
viewController.fromLastScreen = "ProductDetailViewController" 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hi, please provide examples and code.

Comment: @adrisons if I push to second view controller from first view controller having navigation bar hidden and then show navigation bar on second view controller it shows me black space between uiview and navigation bar

Comment: @adrisons . et viewController = PlaceOrderViewController(nibName: "PlaceOrderViewController", bundle: nil)
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        viewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        viewController.fromLastScreen = "ProductDetailViewController"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

Comment: Ok, I added that code to your question